# Which driver to fully support GeForce GT 750M and have QHD resolution working?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, display

Since the install of `Ubuntu 16.04`, I can't configure the display of a `Dell P2416D` to QHD resolution (2560x1440). Note that it was working fine with `14.04`. The video card is a `GeForce GT 750M/PCIe/SSE2`.

All 3 additional drivers have been tested to no avail:

[image]

`NVIDIA X Server Settings` utility is unable to detect displays correctly:

[image]

Command `Xrandr` outputs the following:

[image]

Comment: Please add the output of `xrandr` to your question using a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: @dessert I've updated the post accordingly. Note however that I'm not looking for a tweak using `Xrandr` or a similar method.

Comment: What's wrong with `xrandr`? I think you need to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/957671/edit) your question and add details about what you want here.

Comment: I agrre that using `Xrandr` to add the missing configuration would probably fix the issue. Now, I'd really like to understand why a brand new `16.04` install does not support the resolution whereas `14.04` does. Something looks wrong with the driver, don't you think?

Comment: Well then why didn't you say so in your question? Don't you think *it worked in 14.04* is crucial information? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/957671/edit) and explain your question!

Comment: Question changed. Information added.

Answer (score 0):

To add a missing resolution, first calculate the VESA Coordinated Video Timing mode using `cvt` like so:

```
$ cvt 2560 1440
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

Then register this new mode using the calculated modeline, I use *qhd* as a name here:

```
xrandr --newmode qhd 312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

According to your `xrandr` output the screen for which you want to add the resolution is *eDP-1-1*, so now add the mode to this output using:

```
xrandr --addmode eDP-1-1 qhd
```

Now the resolution should be available in GUI tools and can be chosen there. To set it with `xrandr` do:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode qhd
```